# Can't run synaptic package manager on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, synaptic

I installed synaptic through terminal, but I didn't find it when I search for it, so I uninstalled it. I tried to install it through package manager, I thought it would install more properly. Then I run it while searching and clicking by app launcher. I get prompt for sudo password then nothing happen... I tried to open synaptic through terminal, it worked but I got this error message:

> ```
> Gtk-Message: 18:14:50.057: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. 
> This is discouraged.
> ```

And a pop-up saying:

> ```
> Starting "Synaptic Package Manager" without administrative privileges
>
>   You will not be able to apply any changes, but you can still export
>   the marked changes or create a download script for them.
> ```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 and I'm new to Linux. Can anyone explain to me what happened and help me fix it, thanks.

Comment: Try to launch it from Dash or from Applications menu. If you want to run it from terminal - use `synaptic-pkexec`.

Comment: Did you try `sudo synaptic` from the command line?  The second error seems to suggest you are trying the command without administrator privileges.

Comment: Did you change your default graphics server from xorg to Wayland?

Comment: @K7AAY you are right I tried that before logging in, I wanted to know the difference between those two, still don't understand how it works but I guess wayland block every graphics software needs root access from running however, switching back to X solved the problem

Comment: Then I suggest you click on the checkmark at left to show the answer which solved your problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is a "feature" of Wayland, which prevents GUI software needing root from running via sudo. You can get around it by running

> xhost +si:localuser:root

after logging in. If you often need to use sudo applications you could put this command in a script in your startup applications.

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/xorg-will-be-the-default-in-18-04-lts/3623 indicates xorg is the default, and the OP did not state he was running Wayland.

Comment: The other answer above from N0rbert has also assumed the problem is Wayland, so why only mark my answer down?

Comment: And the OP has now confirmed the problem was Wayland!

Comment: This worked immediately for me.   It also fixed a problem I was having with RealVNC version 5.

Comment: Worked immediately, I would appreciate more in depth explanation or pointer over the Wayland documentation, also how we can assess that Wayland is installed and running. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I you are running Wayland (someone can assess if he's running Wayland by issuing this command into a terminal `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`), and even the new version of X (apparently) are preventing GUI root elevated privilege application execution by default because of the security issues involves with such use case (ref.: https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/wayland, "Why" section 1, sorry in french). 'gksu' or 'gksudo' are not bundle with standard Ubuntu distribution and they shouldn't be used preferably. To temporarily run GUI applications with root elevated privileges someone could submit this command in terminal:

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

Then launch the application (in our case synaptic) the usual way.

**NOTE:** The above command will allow elevated privileged applications to run for the duration of the current Linux session.

It wouldn't be recommended to put it in `.bashrc`.

If you need a proper way to launch elevated privileges applications here a rely good wiki entry that propose a nice workable solution:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland/gks